# Mysql c++ connector error

Tags: c++, mysql

I have made an application in c++. This application is connected to a MySQL database (it uses the mysql c++ connector).

When I run the app in my computer with a local database, everything is ok. But when I run it in my server (centos) with its own database, it returns a sqlException with the message: "The connection is in autoCommit mode".

After that, I cant execute any query.

Somebody knows what is happening? Thanks

EDIT: 
The code I have used to connect with the database

```
driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect(host,user,pass);
con->setSchema(bd);
```

host is the database-host (tcp://IP:PORT)
user is the database-user
pass is the database-pass
bd is the database-name

Comment: Will you please add the code snippet

Answer (score -1):

I faced the exact same issue when I was running it on ubuntu 12.04 and I was linking against libraries downloaded from dev.mysql.com for 12.04 but it got resolved when I instead linked it against libraries for 14.04. I am facing the same issue on RHEL6 for both the RHEL5 and RHEL6 libraries. Maybe you should try installing CentOS7 libraries.